# Node clone all the Node app or just use a different thread for a single process

Tags: node.js, sails.js, pm2, clonenode

I've a question of what is better to increase an app performance. I've a Node-Sails app, that has a  process to build images, this process is taking some seconds to finish, so it slows down the server.

I can node-clone the Sails app (using something like pm2) to use all cores of the CPU, and also I can make the image creation method use a different core of the CPU. But I'm not 100% sure which approach is better, performance and scalability wise.

I'm inclined to clone Sails to use all cores, because in that way I believe will be more efficient, what is your opinion and why?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need multiple instances of the same app, or just multiple instances of the image creation? Does your app have any sort of sessions / state? You may want to consider just using [child_process.fork](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) (or spawn or whatever).

Comment: @dvlsg need multiple instances of the image creation actually. I'll read about the child_process.

Comment: You could certainly accomplish it with multiple instances of the application as well, but if you only need to "thread" that specific function, then `child_process.fork()` would be a solution. You may have to rework the code / move it to a separate node file to make it fit the solution, though, depending on how it is currently written.

Comment: Yes, I know that I can do it both ways, but I'm unsure which is best, to isolate that function or to clone the application. Maybe test both and see which is faster?